# how to select the dropdown value using key press angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular9

The current scenario is in such a way that a drop down containing multiple options.

```
 value: Values[] = [
    { value: '1', viewValue: '1' },
    { value: '2', viewValue: '2' },
    { value: '3', viewValue: '3' }
  ];`



<select formControlName="item">
    <option *ngFor="let i of foods" [value]="i.value">{{i.value}}</option>
  </select>
```

The requirement is that if I click 1 on the keyboard, then the option 1 needs to be selected. I've tried using @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) but didn't worked. Are there any examples that can be used.? How to select the options using the keyboard inputs.??

The sample code of the listener is below.

```
 @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
 handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
 this.keypressed = event.keyCode;
 console.log('this.keypressed', this.keypressed)
 }
```

It works when the drop-down is closed. If the drop-down is opened, then value of this.keypressed is not getting populated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried using @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) but didnt worked

Comment: That should be in your question not in a comment. You should also include the body of The listener function and explain what you mean by didn't work

Comment: This behavior should actually be native to the browser without any extra event binding. Can you post more of your code or reproduce in stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple matSelect, you can use the `(keydown)` event mixed with an `[(ngModel)]` to do it :

```
import {
  Component,
} from "@angular/core";
import { MatSelect } from "@angular/material/select";

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: "select-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "select-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["select-overview-example.css"]
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "Steak" },
    { value: "pizza-1", viewValue: "Pizza" },
    { value: "tacos-2", viewValue: "Tacos" }
  ];
  firstSelect = this.foods[2].value;

  onKeyPressed(event: KeyboardEvent, mySelect: MatSelect) {
    if (event.keyCode - 97 >= 0 && event.keyCode - 97 <= 2) {
      this.firstSelect = this.foods[event.keyCode - 97].value;
      mySelect.close();
    }
  }
}
```

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select #mySelect [(ngModel)]="firstSelect" (keydown)="onKeyPressed($event, mySelect)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvxgyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html).

The select must be focused of course, either by a mouse click or by tabulation on the keyboard.

97 is the ASCII code of the number `1` in the ASCII table.

I tried doing it with a `formControl` but could not achieve to update the selected value in the html. If you know how to do it then you could use it if you need it in a form.